# OG tags are coming on html head page but when I post on LinkedIn no image or title showing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, share-open-graph

I am new to angular, I have added some javascript code to dynamically load of meta tags on site inside index.html.
When I post the url on LinkedIn I don't see image or title is coming in post.

But I can see the meta tags are generating inside inspect element.

Comment: "*some javascript code to dynamically load of meta*" - The chance is great that the LinkedIn scraper doesn't compute javascript though

Comment: How to avoid that, I tried to add those through angular but those are getting appended at the end inside head.

Comment: You'd want to make a shareURL that serves HTML directly from the server.  (make a version of the site that works when Javascript is turned off in the browser.)